# I try to pass object from controller to another controller using factory

Tags: angularjs

I try to pass object from index.html controller(signupCtrl) to connexion.html (controller:affCtrl)and display the object in the form of connexion.html using a factory, I created this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3eMliorLevEAvZVrYW1b?p=preview)

This is the script.js file that contains two controllers

```
'use strict'
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

demoApp.controller('signupCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, per) {
    $scope.envoie = function (user) {
        per = user;
        console.log(per);
        window.location="connexion.html"
    };
});

demoApp.controller('affCtrl', function($rootScope, per) {
    $rootScope.per = per;
});
```

And the factory:

```
demoApp.factory("per",function() {
    return {
        "name":"",
        "password":"",
    }
});
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I try to fill in the form of page connexion.html from the data introduced in index.htm

Comment: @EdwardKnowles can you help me

Comment: @mrmadou have a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/H4SVl6?p=preview

Comment: @mrmadou and this http://plnkr.co/edit/tg25kr?p=preview