# Adding Google Maps API to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I need to include Google Maps API in my AngularJS application. To do so, I've created this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NkxVGbMQmDFt5TKoYyI7?p=preview) from this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc7Uu/854/).

I think I have to edit `index.html` but I do not know how.. Thanks for your help

index.html:

```
<div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
        <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: glad to be of help :)

Comment: thank's for your help @rachel .. please can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047641/i-try-to-pass-object-from-controller-to-another-controller-using-factory , I start with angularjs and it'svery hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jXABQ7yHPnKjheDBqToR?p=preview). ideally put the script that i've put in script tags in a javascript file (save as all files> .js) and then link it in as `<script src= "location.js"></script>` or whatever  you call it (make sure your path is correct). put the style in a css stylesheet and include it like `<link rel = "stylesheet" src="style.css">` or whatever.

don't forget to include

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&extension=.js"></script>
```

you didn't have this in your initial plunker. it was an external resource in the fiddle.